# Why is the compiler giving me an error with writeInt?

Tags: java

I was making a DAT file with 3 int numbers but when I use writeInt to write the the compiler gives me an error on the writeInt, what I have to do.

```
import java.io.*;


public class Esercizio010916 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String Path ="C:\\Users\\Enzo\\Documents\\compiti informatica\\Esercizi\\Corso di recupero 2016\\Esercizio 01.09.16\\";

        String nomeDat = "Quantità.dat";

        String nomeCsv = "Oggetti.csv";

        String PathDat = Path + nomeDat;

        String PathCsv = Path + nomeCsv;

        CreaDat(PathDat);
    }

    public static void CreaDat(String PathDat){
       int n1;

       int n2;

       int n3;

        try{

            FileInputStream fileFisico = new FileInputStream(PathDat);

            DataInputStream fileLogico = new DataInputStream(fileFisico);

            n1 = Console.readInt("Inserisci il valore di n1 \n");

            n2 = Console.readInt("Inserisci il valore di n2 \n");

            n3 = Console.readInt("Inserisci il valore di n3 \n");

            fileLogico.writeInt(n1);


            fileLogico.close();

        }catch(IOException e){

            System.out.println("IOException e");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Because there is no method `writeInt` in class `DataInputStream`

Comment: The error is on the writeInt and it says "Cannot find symbo; Symbol method writeInt(int); location fileLogico of type DataInputStream"

Comment: I suggest you move the `fileLogico` and `fileFisico` into a try-with-resource block.

Comment: I've already found an answer (Changing FileIntputStream with FileOutputStream) but thank you anywat

Answer (score 2):

Change `DataInputStream` with `DataOutputStream`.

The output-stream classes are used by the program to write bytes to something (like file, console, etc.), while the input-stream ones are used for reading from something (file, console, etc).

Of course, then you'll have to change `FileInputStream` with `FileOutputStream`, also.